# onChange event with HorizontalSlider created declarative

Tags: javascript, dojo, declarative

I'm trying to created a HorizontalSlider declarative that sends its values to a textbox, but I don't get any values in the textbox.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
"dojo/parser",
"dojo/dom",
"dijit/form/HorizontalSlider",
"dijit/form/TextBox"],
function(parser, dom, HorizontalSlider, TextBox)
{parser.parse();});
</script>

<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/HorizontalSlider" id="slider_BM_FE" data-dojo-props="minimum: 0, maximum: 100000, value: 19423, intermediateChanges: true, onChange:function(value){dom.byId('BM_FE').value = value;}"/>
<br>
<input type="text" id="BM_FE" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" style="width:100px; color:black"/>
```

What is wrong with that? I'm just seeing the Slider and it works itself, but it does not enter values into the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Since your textbox is a dijit widget instead of using dom.by try using registry.byId from dijit/registry to set the value of the textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
"dojo/parser",
"dojo/dom",
"dijit/form/HorizontalSlider",
"dijit/form/TextBox",
"dijit/registry"],
function(parser, dom, HorizontalSlider, TextBox, registry)
{parser.parse();});
</script>

<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/HorizontalSlider" id="slider_BM_FE" data-dojo-props="minimum: 0, maximum: 100000, value: 19423, intermediateChanges: true, onChange:function(value){registry.byId('BM_FE').set({value: value})}"/>
<br>
<input type="text" id="BM_FE" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" style="width:100px; color:black"/>
```

Comment: I tried it, but that doesn't work either- When looking at it with Firebug I get the same error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: dom is not defined"/"Uncaught ReferenceError: registry is not defined"

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your work and provide the link in the comments

Comment: Yes, i can. There's not all functionality of the application in it, but everything needed for that slider problem. http://jsfiddle.net/7qf1ouz9/ The slider can be found in the container named "Planungstool"

Comment: And the html-code for the slider starts in line 28.

Comment: The problem is that the "dom" module wasn't being loaded.  Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/kagant15/7qf1ouz9/1/

Comment: well that is strange, because i added it with 'require(["dojo/dom"])' and it is now working in the fiddle but not in my application. did you change something more than loading it via 'dojo.require("dojo.dom")' and changing 'dom.byId' to 'dojo.dom.byId'?

Comment: No that's all I changed.  Are you getting the same error?

Comment: OK. No, the error is now: "Error undefined running custom onLoad code: This deferred has already been resolved"